# How does the current of RS485 signals return from the receiver to the sender?

Tags: differential, rs485, ground-loop, serial-bus, single-ended

I am planning a system consisting of **1 master device** which is connected to **19 slave devices** using **RS485 transceivers**. Also, all devices are powered by **1 PSU**. A simplified schematic is shown below.

[image: Schematic]

As you can see in the schematic, the slaves each control a **4W LED** using **PWM**. I added this detail because I want to show that due to the switched loads a not unsubstantial current flows through the GND line. Therefore, due to the impedance of the GND line, the GND potential should be slightly different for each slave.

The bus should only be operated with a data rate of **250KBit/s**. With a rise time of **180ns** this would lead to a bandwidth of about **2MHz**. However, I would also be very interested in what would happen if a data rate of **10MBit/s** were used. With a rise time of **8ns** this would lead to a bandwidth of **40MHz**.

Since I am currently studying **EMC aspects**, I would be very interested to know the answer to the following question.

**1.)** **How exactly do the current loops look when the master is communicating with the slaves?**

While researching the exact operation of RS485, I came to the conclusion that the **differential** signal pair (A, B) of the transceiver are actually two **single ended** signals ([Source 1](https://www.planetanalog.com/signal-chain-basics-84-why-rs485-does-not-need-ground-wires/#), [Source 2](https://www2.htw-dresden.de/%7Ehuhle/ArtScienceRS485.pdf)). This would mean that the current of the two signals would flow from the transmitter to the receivers and then back via ground. Thus, the outgoing and return paths of the current do not only consist of the signal lines A and B. So looking only on signal line A I came to the following current loop.

[image: Schematic with current loop]

The red path is the outgoing current path and the green path is the current return path.

Since this current loop covers a larger area and permanently conducts higher frequency signals, I am concerned that this could cause some EMC issues. Also, at higher frequencies, the current return path may seek other unwanted paths back to the receiver, as the GND line is likely to have a significant inductive component. So, I would be interested in the answers to the following questions.

**2.)** **How can I design a better current return path even for high frequencies?**

**3.)** **Are there other communication standards that might be better for this purpose?**

### Additional notes:

**Why don't I use isolated RS485 transceivers?**
Isolated RS485 transceivers are not an option for economic reasons.

**Why don't I use an additional GND line together with the A and B line?**
On the one hand this would form ground loops and on the other the return current of the LEDs would then be divided between the two GND lines. This could cause a not insignificant current to flow through the master back to the PSU. This could not only cause disturbances in the electronics of the master, but could also exceed the maximum allowable current that the master board can conduct. Also, the additional ground wire would have to have a similar cross section as the other one. This is expensive and takes up a lot of space.

**How is the data bus cable configured?**
Since the slaves are very closely spaced and therefore the data bus cable has a stub every 10cm, a twisted pair cable without shielding is used.

Comment: You're missing a major part of this DC current flow.  Most of the current flows though the two parallel termination resistors.

Comment: The two ground currents from the two 'single ended' lines are in opposition, and as such, no ground current flows. The **whole point** of a differential line is that it's differential, all the current that goes out on one line returns on the other line, not ground.

Comment: No (at least from a high frequency standpoint).  Depends on the type of interface.  With a stripline or microstrip interface, you have two currents, moving in opposite directions, under the individual traces of the diff pair.  For a DC signal, you are correct.

Comment: @Neil_UK - RS-485 signaling is not a current loop. The driver drives both lines with a positive voltage with respect to ground. The current flowing *into* each line from the driver to the receiver(s) returns through the ground wire.

Comment: @brhans That is true, any current not returning via data bus will return via ground - but there just is not much impedance to allow current to flow from receiver input to ground, or to supply for that matter. Single-ended input impedance of a receiver is commonly balanced and in the order of far more than 12k per input. So applying 5V to both A and B inputs of a receiver will result into ground current far less than 1mA per receiver. In the more common scenario, less than 0.5mA would flow into one receiver input, and approximately same amount would flow out from the other receiver input.

Comment: @brhans The line is balanced. The termination resistor is connected between the balanced lines. It;s a transmission line. AC, that is EMI inducing currents, flow out on one line and back on the other. That is the meaning of a balanced differential line. It does not matter where DC bias current flows, it's not EMI inducing. Signal current doesn't care whether you call it currnet loop or not, which phrase usually refers to a 4-20 mA signalling loop which is a totally different beast. Think of it as the two transmitters each generating a signal voltage and signal current, and they are opposite

Comment: @Neil_UK "It;s a transmission line. AC, that is EMI inducing currents, flow out on one line and back on the other. That is the meaning of a balanced differential line. " RS485 _is_ (usually) balanced, but that is not the definition. The definition of a balanced line requires that the impedance to ground of both lines is equal. With all RS485 transceivers of which I am aware, this condition is satisfied, and the spec _may_ require this (within some tolerance), although I am not aware that it does.

Comment: @Neil_UK - "EMI inducing currents, flow out on one line and back on the other. That is the meaning of a balanced differential line."  I don't think that is correct.  Assuming this interferer is far away, the EMI induced currents flow in the same direction and at the same amplitude (for a broadside source) on both lines of the diff interface.  This interferer voltage is a common mode voltage, which is rejected by the diff input stage of the receiver, so long as the common mode range of the receiver is not exceeded.

Comment: @SteveSh I was referring to EMI generated by the 485 transmitter, not to external interferers which might happen to get picked up by the conductors. The first is a function of the 485 setup, the second is not.

Comment: That wasn't clear.

Comment: One last comment to the OP - This was very nice grounding/return current diagram you put together.  If you had included the power supplies/power system in this, it would have been CDR (Critical Desig Review) category.  Nice job.

Answer (score 6):

**1.) How exactly the current loops look when the master is communicating with the slaves?**

For high speed signals (not DC), the answer depends on whether the interface is stripline/microstrip (trace over GND) or twisted pairs.

In the first case, the return current for each signal of the diff pair flows directly under the trace carrying the signal, assuming the GND plane is uninterrupted.  This is because the individual traces couple much more strongly to the return plane than they do to each other.  It is a mis-statement to say that the + and - currents cancel.  They each flow independently under their respective signal trace.

In the second case, the individual wires of the twisted pair couple to each other much more strongly than they couple to their surroundings.  So in this case it is accurate to say that the current from one wire returns along the other.

Now if there is an imbalance in the two signals of the diff pair (slightly different delays or skews or amplitudes), this causes a common mode current to flow along both traces.  This common mode current also flows in a loop, and needs to be returned back to the driving source.  This current will flow such as to minimize the total loop inductance, which means minimizing the loop area of the current.

In the stripline/microstrip configuration, this return path is through the GND plane.  In the twisted pair configuration, this path may be through chassis and structure connections (not desirable), or through the shield of the cable carrying the twisted pairs.

**2.) How can I design a better current return path even for high frequencies?**

In a nutshell, minimize the loop area in which the currents flow.

Also, look at this post: [Where does return current flow for a differential signal?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/448221/where-does-return-current-flow-for-a-differential-signal)

**Comment on the green return path**

What you showed as the return path for current - the green path in your diagram - is correct for the input currents that flow into, or out of, the individual inputs of the diff receivers.  This current is usually on the order of microamps or tens of microamps, depending on the particulars of the receiver you are using, and needs to return back to the driver.  In your diagram, the green path is the only way for this current to flow.  Note that there may be some other sneak path through chassis/structure involved, depending on how your power system is implemented and grounded.  Also this current is more or less DC.

Comment: Thank you, this answer helps me a lot. Some questions come to my mind:
1a) What is important in the transition from PCB to cable, i.e. from stripline/microstrip to twisted-pair?
1b) How could I formulate this transition mathematically? 
1c) Should the characteristic impedance of the stripline/microstrip with respect to GND be the same as that between the two wires of the twisted-pair cable? 
2) Instead of minimizing the loop area, can't I use a ferrite choke to reduce the common mode current? Or can this have bad effects on the data transmission?

Comment: You want the characteristic impedance of all the interfaces to be the same, within 20%.  Whether that target impedance is 90 ohms, 100 ohms, or 110 ohms really doesn't matter, so long as your drivers can supply the necessary current given the double terminations.  For RS-485the connectors probably don't matter as they are electrically short compareterestd to the frequencies of interest.

Comment: The ZO of the stubs really doesn't matter, since they are unterminated at their ends (the input of the receivers).

Comment: the receivers are high impedance, very little current flows on the receiver PCB

Comment: @Jasen - Yes, except for input current leakage.

Comment: 1a) `What is important in the transition from PCB to cable` on the receiver **all stubs are bad**. Put the receiver IC next to the terminal where the wire connects. If you can't do that have the impedance as high as possible. - thin traces well spaced,  no ground plane etc.

Comment: @Jasen - I Disagree.  All stubs are not automatically bad.  Maybe a better way to put it would be to say that in many cases stubs can be tolerated.  It all depends on the length of the stubs and the frequency (usually related to the edge rates) of interest.  Having the receiver next to the terminal is best.  But if that cannot be accomplished, making the impedance (of the interface?) as high as possible really doesn't matter.  This is where a SI analysis tool is your best friend.

Comment: @SteveSh Not many people know or care about this, but the minimal stub length _can_ be important too, when the nodes are closely spaced. Take a look at #10 in [TI design guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla272d/slla272d.pdf).

Comment: @Maple - Having nodes (stubs with lengths less than say 8" or 12" for RS-485) close together on the main run such as a multi-drop backplane just increases the capacitance at that location on the bus.  The spacial extent of that local capacitance is "short" compared to the rise/fall time of the RS-485 signal, and really doesn't affect the signal very much.

Answer (score 3):

From https://www2.htw-dresden.de/%7Ehuhle/ArtScienceRS485.pdf

> Signals A and B are complementary, but this doesn’t imply that one
> signal is a current return for the other. RS-485 is not a current
> loop.
>
> The drivers and receivers must share a common ground. This is  why
> “two-wire network” is a misnomer when applied to RS-485.

Differential transmission with RS-485 requires that the common mode voltage limits are met. The common ground should avoid larger potential differences between the stations. A galvanic isolation between several stations would not work.

If you want larger potential differences youd should look at isolated RS-485 tranceivers like the [ADM2485](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM2485.pdf) or [ISO35T](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso35t.pdf).

Comment: What you said is correct, but is really not relevant IMM, to the OP's question about return currents.  Nowhere did he mention or ask about common mode voltage limits.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a detailed answer (you got plenty of those already), but rather a comment on one misconception that seems to be a driving force behind your question.

> ...due to the switched loads a not unsubstantial current flows through
> the GND line. Therefore, due to the impedance of the GND line, the GND
> potential should be slightly different for each slave.

The problem is, the GND potential, as measured against some common ground, *does not depend on the current in a wire*. If you measure voltage between two ends then sure, it will depend on current and can be huge. But common mode voltage does not work this way. If, due to some environmental conditions, you have variations of GND potential then the same conditions are usually applicable to the signal wires as well. That is the whole point of running ground wire along with signals even when differential signalling is used - to balance out common mode voltage. And yes, to provide signal return path, with currents that can be minuscule comparing to total current in a wire but still work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

RS-485 using Belden low capacitance 120 ohm STP dual-shielded cable may be limited to 150 MHz-m BW-length product and 20MHz max typically, I believe due to parasitic port capacitance and ESL 10nH/cm which is easily modelled on Falstad's site.

So for 0.25 m trunk you have excess BW and in theory could extend that to 150 MHz-m/40 MHz about 4m.  The CMRR problems arise when end devices have CM noise C coupled from their isolation Tfmr causing poor BER. If so, to raise CM impedance and isolate gnds, an AC protocol like BiPhase or RLL is used in ethernet protocol using an AC coupled R+C secondary center tap diff. mode  and CM choke combined into a "hybrid" Tfmr for the PHY.

The nonlinear attenuation of harmonics may pose some ISI or jitter that is pattern dependent with 1T,2T bandwidths can be observed if a problem with a cable and even pre-compensated as was done for magnetic recording but is probably not necessary unless you were going for 20Mbps.

- thus matching driver impedance to 120 trunk is essential
- The EMI is due to unbalanced coupling of each twisted line to double shields.  If there is ground current, this can be measured if it contains noise or how much signal emitted using a scope 10:1 probe wrapped around cable with a very short ground loop to minimize coax resonance or raise resonant f > 40 MHz or some better current probe.

Your biggest emission source is likely the parasitic inductance not balanced to LEDs with PWM. So consider slew rate reduction & STP cable if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You want 1 master and 19 slaves powered by the same PSU, signal frequency 250 KBit/s, 10 cm flat cable between two slaves.

So total length of the bus is only 2 m, the frequency is well below 10 MHz, that is no problem at all using RS-485. I would recommend bus termination at both ends

Answer (score -1):

You are neglecting that at the exact same time that one of the differential lines is going positive, the other is going negative. The two lines are terminated at their ends with a resistor (commonly 120 ohm). One output of the driver will be sourcing current, while the other will be sinking. This situation will reverse depending upon whether a one or zero is being transmitted.

The two currents are equal and opposite and do cancel. All that is left in the ground circuit is the DC current driving the inputs. The receives are high-impedance relative to the terminations so most of the current flows through the differential lines from one driver output then back to the other. Very little flows through the ground.

During transitions there will be some current into the ground into the capacitance that each line has to ground. This should be largely canceled depending upon how well the differential lines are matched - with perfect matching no ground AC current would flow at all.

Comment: On the one hand I understand this view, on the other hand I am not sure if one can see it so simple and rely only on the circuit theory. If you take a closer look on how signals propagate on lines and on PCBs, I have my doubts.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ke9ZQTVHB7U
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdzetSQ2dMk

Comment: @Michael - yes there will be ground currents induced by the transitions. But they will be canceled by the opposite polarity currents from the other output; The two lines need to be close together so as to minimize the loop area between the positive and negative signals. They would usually be spaced apart on the PCB to give the required differential impedance. Typically 120ohm for RS485.

Comment: RS-486 is not a current loop. Neither of the signal lines is ever supposed to go negative with respect ground under normal circumstances. Current is only ever sourced by the driver, not sunk. This current flows through the receiver(s) and returns through the ground wire.

Comment: @brhans That's not how RS-485 works. Based on logic 1 or 0 to be transmitted, driver will drive one data wire high to VCC and the other data wire low to GND so both data pins do source and sink current.

Comment: @brhans Neither signal line goes -ve wrt ground. That's true, but irrelevant. Current is only ever sourced? No, a low-going tranmistter has to sink the AC current component of the signal, regardless of whether it's still sourcing any DC current. The DC bias current is irrelevant in this context.

Answer (score -1):

1. For all purposes, you can think that RS-485 receiver is a high impedance input in practice, and data wires are differential, so whatever goes out on transmitter A pin is sunk by transmitter B pin, and it would flow via the termination resistors. No data wire current would end up in VCC or ground on the receivers, under normal conditions, at least not not by any significant amount you should be concerned of. And since twisted pair of wires are used for the differential data, the loop area will be small, and would efficiently cancel magnetic coupling.
2. Since your question seems to base on a false assumption how RS-485 works, maybe you don't need a better current path.
3. RS-485 should work just fine. One transmitter, 19 receivers, 250 kbps, used for sending commands to lights - you have basically re-invented DMX-512 by accident.

Comment: On the one hand I understand this view, on the other hand I am not sure if one can see it so simple and rely only on the circuit theory. If you take a closer look on how signals propagate on lines and on PCBs, I have my doubts.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ke9ZQTVHB7U
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdzetSQ2dMk

Comment: What doubts you have? Why are you not sure? If you don't agree with my answer and downvote it, you must be sure why and have a counter-argument which I can comment on.

Comment: First of all, I did not downvote your post. That must have been someone else. Secondly, I am not sure about the physical processes that are not covered by simple circuit theory. Similar to what you see in the two videos I linked. Just as described in SteveSh's answer, there are additional phenomena that may cause problems.

Comment: @Michael OK - Well your bus is unshielded twisted pair so you don't have a ground plane surrounding the bus wires and if you don't have ground plane on PCB under bus wires then nothing interesting happens. Only if there is imbalance in the impedances of bus wires then that will turn into common mode noise and will return in ground wire. The imbalance will be small, as RS-485 transceivers have high impedance input, and most of the impedance is defined by the 100 to 120 ohm twisted pair impedance and termination. The RS-485 bus is differential and balanced.

Comment: I did not down vote your answer.  But your comment that "No data wire current would end up in VCC or ground on the receivers, under normal conditions, at least not not by any significant amount..." deserves some comment.  What you said is true IFF the + and - outputs of the driver are perfectly matched.  This is not the case in reality, and any unbalance results in a common mode current that flows through ground or VCC.

Comment: @SteveSh I agree, and in real life, there is always slight imbalance - my point being, if/when there is imbalance, how much there will be imbalance, and will it have any significant role in the circuit. RS-485 can handle +/- 7V of common mode voltage difference. It really takes effort to design something like the wire thickness quite wrong to get 7V voltage difference in a 12V system, over 2.5 meters of wire.

Comment: @Justme - My comments about common mode currents had nothing to do with common mode voltage ranges or rejections.  But rather that those currents must return back to the source via some route.  And the smaller the total loop, the better.  This may or may not have any affect on circuit operation, but could have a impact on EMC compliance.  According to some industry experts, the failure to meet radiated emission (RE) limits can be caused by a current as low a 5 uA, (Eric Bogatin Rules of Thumb #31).

Answer (score -1):

https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/oth/tb506-functional-principles-rs-485-drivers-and-receivers
The output stage of an RS-485 driver is a H-bridge, where the upper transistor in one leg sources a current and the lower transistor in the other leg sinks current. This current flows through the external load in one direction when A=high and B=low, and in the opposite direction when B=high and A=low. Each transistor has a schottky diode in series to prevent reverse current flow. Hence, only one output drives the line at a time, never both at the same time. So, there is always a return path without a ground wire.
Also, the receiver inputs are internally biased and thus, do not require a ground wire to establish an input reference.
**THUS, RS-485 IS A TRUE 2-WIRE INTERFACE.**
TK

Comment: No.  It needs a 3rd connection to establish, or limit the common mode voltage between the driver and the receiver.  The differences between the ground references, if you will, between the two boxes.  You also need that path for common mode currents caused by slight differences between the A & B side driver.

Comment: But what you said is fine from a static, DC standpoint.  It breaks down when talking about AC/switching conditions.

Comment: No, it is not a true 2-wire bus. Even the RS-485 standard says it isn't, and like many people here have asked why it does not work with only two wires in their system because they think it's a 2-wire system, so you must be wrong saying it is a true 2-wire system. It does not work if one system sends 5V/0V, and the other system has 105V/100V at receiver, it is likely beyond common mode operating range, and also damaged beyond repair.

Comment: This is because you are highly exceeding the specified common-mode range. If you are staying within the common-mode range, then RS-485 is a 2-wire bus, because the receiver inputs are internally biased!